# Can anyone tell me how to get Ubuntu to look like Karmic Koala 9.10?

Tags: gnome, themes, 9.10, gnome-flashback, gnome2

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (standard), with GNOME Flashback.

9.10 was my first Ubuntu and I'm feeling nostalgic. I've managed to get as far as 'Classic GNOME Flashback' and change the wallpaper, but I'm hoping someone knows how to get the theme just right. I have tried doing the steps given in the forum thread [how to get old ubuntu theme? like in karmic?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1853899) but I can't get them to work.  I got stuck on the [last 2 comments](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1853899&p=11308089#post11308089).

I basically would like the human theme, looking like with the show desktop button, applications icon and computer icon in the corners to match Karmic Koala. (See the old article [Review: Ubuntu 9.10 first look](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/technology/review-ubuntu-910-first-look/article4292498/).)

It's just for nostalgia, I've been looking into this for hours and struggling.

Comment: Okay sorry, I'm using  ubuntu 20.04 (standard), with gnome flashback. I basically would like the human theme,  looking like with the show desktop button, applications icon and computer icon in the corners to match karmic koala.  https://www.theglobeandmail.com/technology/review-ubuntu-910-first-look/article4292498/ .  It's just for nostalgia, I've been looking into this for hours and struggling.

Comment: I think [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) is what you are looking for.  Ubuntu MATE is an official Ubuntu flavor with the MATE desktop. The MATE desktop is a fork of GNOME 2, which was the desktop environment used in Karmic.  If you want it to be perfect, you're going to have to spend a lot of time customizing each element and you may not get there exactly.  You're talking about a 10+ year old operating system after all.

Comment: I would boot up the release you want (VM or in 'live' mode using "try Ubunty"), note what themes etc is uses (I'd even make a copy (`scp` etc) of them in case they've changed) and then use those on a modern system. These will likely be GTK2 (so old & maybe not possible in all environments), but I'd agree with @Nmath in I'd expect pretty good results with MATE, maybe even XFCE/Xubuntu (even LXQt/Lubuntu will can look like it, but it won't use GTK2 themes on it's desktop so you'd have to do it yourself); but MATE (XFCE 2nd) would most operate like it too.